# get help text of system command button?

Tags: axapta, x++, microsoft-dynamics

how can i get helptext of system command button , i use a class to browse a node of a form and get helptext of controls contained in the form, i have not to use the tooltip method cause i will use  the formrun object and it doesn't work correctly and degrades performance

i use a program like this :

```
runnode = treenode::findNode(#FormsPath);
form = runnode.AOTfindChild("name of the form ");
formBuildDesign = form.design();
formGridControl = formBuildDesign.control("DeleteCode");
idx= formGridControl.id();
args = new Args();
args.object(form); 

// Create the run-time form.
// formRun = classfactory.formRunClass(args);

  formRun.init();

  formGridControl = formRun.control(idx);

 info(strFmt("helptext: %1",syslabeledit.findLabel("FR",formRun.control(idx).toolTip())));

 it works for the first time , but after it make Ax crash
```

thank's in advance

Answer (score 3):

Your code crashes when you call the init() method the second time. 
You can use the TreeNodeTraverserControls class to traverse the control nodes of a form design. 
The following example demonstrates this:

```
static void GetHelpTextFromNewButton(Args _args)
{
    #AOT
    #Properties
    TreeNode formnode, treenode;

    TreeNodeTraverserControls traverser;

    formnode = treenode::findNode(#FormsPath + "\\custtable\\Designs\\Design");

    traverser = new TreeNodeTraverserControls(formnode);

    while(traverser.next())
    {
        treenode = traverser.currentNode();

        if(treenode.AOTname() =="cmdbtnCustomerNew")
        {
            info(strFmt("helptext: %1 %2",treenode.AOTgetProperty(#PropertyHelpText), SysLabel::labelId2String(treenode.AOTgetProperty(#PropertyHelpText), "FR")));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it also uses the SysLabel::labelId2String method to get the label in the language of you choice. This is better than using syslabeledit. 
Using this code, it is also unnecessary to construct the actual form and thus it should also be possible to run this code in batch.

Edit:
For command buttons that don't have a help text label set, the label is indeed empty, because the property doesn't contain a label. 
In this case you can get the command property in the same way as the help text property:

```
treenode.AOTgetProperty(#PropertyCommand)
```

This will return an integer value which you can switch on. Simple return the label that is used by that command button because it is always the same "Create a new record" in en-us. 
I do not believe that the helptext and label property are defined in ax somewhere you can automatically retrieve it. 
The are defined in the kernel text data files. You can find these in the bin directory of the aos. Take the AxSysEN-US.ktd file for example. Search for "#1001". This lists all labels that are used for the command buttons in en-us. A similar file exists for other languages. 
For the new button, an entry reads:

```
0x0104 &New | Create a new record
```

The "0x0104" is the id of the command which you can also see when selecting the command on your command button. 0x0104 is the heximal representation of 260, which is what the PropertyCommand property will return in AX.

Edit 2:
As an alternative, you could use this code to work with tooltip(), this does return the label, but only in one language:

```
Args args;
formrun formrun;

args = new Args();
args.name(formStr(CustTable));

formRun = classfactory.formRunClass(args);
formRun.init();

info(strFmt("helptext: %1",formrun.control(formrun.controlId("cmdbtnCustomerNew")).toolTip())); // ok
info(strFmt("helptext: %1",SysLabel::labelId2String(formrun.control(formrun.controlId("cmdbtnCustomerNew")).toolTip(), "FR"))); // nok
```

The problem however is that the tooltip does not return a label so you cannot translate it.

Edit 4:
By the way, you can use this code to translate the text from say en-us to fr:

```
info(sysLabel::labelId2String(syslabeledit.findLabel("en-us", SysLabel::seachStringBuildExactStr(formrun.control(formrun.controlId("cmdbtnCustomerNew")).toolTip())), "fr"));
```

You were on the right track using syslabeledit after all. I'm unsure if all labels used by command buttons are available as translated labels though.

Comment: thanks for your answer , but i have to get a system command button like new , delete .. , the helptext property is empty ??? only then property command is filled

Comment: But if i execute my class for the second time Ax will crashe , cause it called the init method 2 time and its allowed just 1 call   per session

Comment: Does the second example (edit 2) also crash when you call it the second time? In my job it didn't crash.

Comment: hi ,i have to get acces path of form like shown in the adress bar of workspace

Comment: Hi user3203594, it's best to create a new question